# included the module but still getting uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

My Helper file looks like this:

/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end

  # Helper for the sidebar menu highlighting
  def is_active?(page_name)
    if controller_name == "pages"
      "active" if action_name == page_name
    else
      "active" if controller_name == page_name
    end
  end

  # Set correct bootstrap flash messages design
  def bootstrap_class_for flash_type
    case flash_type
      when :success
        "alert-success" # Green
      when :error
        "alert-danger" # Red
      when :alert
        "alert-warning" # Yellow
      when :notice
        "alert-info" # Blue
      else
        flash_type.to_s
    end
  end

end
```

/support/utilities.rb

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do

  describe "full_title" do

    it "should include the page title" do
      full_title('foo').should =~ /foo/
    end

    it "should include the base title" do
      full_title('foo').should =~ /^Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App/
    end

    it "should not include a bar on the home page" do
      full_title('').should_not =~ /\|/
    end
  end
end
```

I want to test my application full_title helper using following spec. I am getting the **"uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper (NameError)"** error but I do not understand why. I have included the ApplicationHelper file.

Does anybody have an idea where it goes wrong?

uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper (NameError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reverted to the  gem 'rspec-rails', '~>2.14.1' and it works again!

Comment: According to the tutorial, you should be using exact version numbers for gems, and according to the online version of the tutorial, rspec-rails should be: `gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'`  If you blow that off, you can expect weird errors.  So I guess the question is: "Why aren't you actually following the tutorial?"  Are you reading the book?  Does the book use more recent versions of gems than the online tutorial?

Comment: I read the book and did like they told me. Now I am creating an app on my own and I would like to learn how to work with the updated gems. I learned now that I can better stay away from beta stuff.

Comment: Okay.  Good luck.  ++ for coming back and posting your solution.